# Using osmviz in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error, openstreetmap

I am trying to use the osmviz module of Python, which allows to use maps from OpenStreetMap.

So I downloaded it with pip, and then I tried to run one of the examples offered by the documentation page of osmviz (https://hugovk.github.io/osmviz/html/doc.html), the third one (https://hugovk.github.io/osmviz/html/pil_example.py.html).

However it doesn't work, I keep getting the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "testosm.py", line 1, in <module>
from osmviz.manager import PILImageManager, OSMManager
File "/home/FUNDP/mcohilis/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/osmviz/manager.py", line 60
raise Exception, "UNIMPLEMENTED"
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So the error seems to be inside the module code and is a syntax error, which I find very weird. What could I do about it?
I get the same error with another code using osmviz, and I tried with two different computers, it doesn't change anything.
Does someone know how to use osmviz ?

Thanks a lot,

Marie

Comment: Try to use osmviz with Python2